# ¿Es correcto el uso de "malamente" en vez de "de mala manera"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adverbios

Muchas veces, sobre todo —creo yo— en textos o discursos de carácter jurídico, está presente el adverbio *malamente*, palabra que corresponde a la típica adverbialización de un adjetivo mediante el uso del sufijo "-mente".

Unos ejemplos:

> **Malamente** puedes tú sugerir que el acusado haya estado en el lugar del crimen.
>
> El cansancio sería la primera razón, era muy desmoralizante hacer giras **malamente** organizadas que no compensaban el dinero que perdíamos por no ir a trabajar.

Otros ejemplos de su uso se pueden observar a través de [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=spanish&query=malamente).

Según la [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/malamente), es simplemente un adverbio de modo, sinónimo de *mal*.

En mi opinión no suena muy bien, y casi siempre es reemplazable ya sea por *mal*, *de mala manera* o *con mala intención*.

¿Existe evidencia de que sea un uso aceptado y/o correcto en el lenguaje moderno?

Comment: En Andalucía se usa mucho.

Comment: Viendo una película situada en Andalucía oí un _Aquí tampoco se está tan malamente_ muy interesante.

Comment: Yo prefiero usar el término mal o muy mal.
Malamente- no es muy idiomático, sobre todo al traducirse del Ingles al Español.
En el contexto de una encuesta se podría usar malamente?
cuando las opciones en ingles son Very badly
Badly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Este hilo](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=35472) del foro del Instituto Cervantes reproduce una consulta similar. Hay una aportación que enumera autores modernos que han usado el adverbio en sus obras:

> Martín Gaite, Carmen; Jodorowsky, Alejandro; Laín Entralgo, Pedro; Castilla del Pino, Carlos; Moix, Ana María; Arrabal, Fernando; Caballero Bonald, José Manuel; Marías, Javier; Chacón, Dulce; Fernán Gómez, Fernando; Leguineche, Manuel; Marsillach, Adolfo; Cela y Trulock, Camilo José; Grandes, Almudena; Molina Foix, Vicente; Bayly, Jaime; Sastre, Alfonso; Tusquets, Esther; Quiñones, Fernando; Cabrera Infante, Guillermo y Cortázar, Julio.

Aunque el usuario no explica cómo ha compilado la lista, he decidido validar algunos y no puedo decir que falte a la verdad.

Así que entiendo que el uso es aceptado (si está en el DLE es porque ha sufrido la validación de los hispanohablantes de a pie y de la academia de la lengua) y es correcto usarlo como adverbio de modo (es así como aparece usado por autores de los que "nos podemos fiar").

> Y bajo el antifaz del arrojo, **malamente** sujeto al rostro, se esforzaban los jóvenes por dominar su timidez, nunca por cultivarla. ([ejemplo de Martín Gaite](http://inabima.gob.do/descargas/bibliotecaFAIL/Autores%20Extranjeros/M/Martin%20Gaite,%20Carmen/Martin%20Gaite,%20Carmen%20-%20Usos%20amorosos%20de%20la%20posguerra%20espanola%20%281.1%29.pdf))
>
> [...] un viento desganado tiraba contra la ventana **malamente** iluminada ([ejemplo de La Rayuela, de Julio Cortázar](http://www.literaberinto.com/Cortazar/rayuela10.htm))
>
> [...] olvidaos de los amores que **malamente** acabaron ([Ejemplo de Fernándo Fernán Gómez](http://elpais.com/diario/1984/05/13/madrid/453295459_850215.html))

Comment: Está en el diccionario probablemente porque existe tanto una forma regular como irregular y así si el lector ve un, no tiene que dudarse por la existencia de la otra (ya estaba en el diccionario de autoridades de 1734).  De hecho, la definición de la forma irregular *mal* en dicho diccionario es «Usado como adverbio, equivale a Malamente, o injustamente: y assí se dice, Mal se ha portado, escribe mal, &c».

Comment: Y yo que pensaba que era influencia del catalán, en Barcelona fue la primera vez que lo oí.

Answer (score 2):

Yo personalmente uso y he oido usar `malamente` de vez en cuando con el significado de con mucha dificultad/a duras penas.

(Castilla y Leon, España).

Comment: Yo también lo uso con el significado que comentas (País Vasco).